# NYC - Does New York City tax scale similar to Federal taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, new-york

As far as I understand it:

If I make 5k yearly versus making 50k yearly I fall into a different federal tax bracket and the amount I'm taxed becomes modified (this is the simple explanation).

**Question**

Does anything like this exist for the nyc tax bracket or is it a flat tax? What about for people who make less than 5k yearly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

New York City income tax is progressive, just like federal income tax. If you look at page 69 of form IT-201-I [available here from the New York State Department of Taxation and Finance](https://www.tax.ny.gov/forms/income_fullyear_forms.htm), you'll see a table of how to apply the tax brackets depending on marital status.

[image]